Subscription (Upgrade Error): "Something went wrong on our end. Please try again later."
I wanted to ask for some help with an issue we're encountering with our Upgrade and Downgrade subscription feature. We've been focusing on implementing the upgrade functionality, and while it works fine during testing with a TestCard (takes about an hour to upgrade from one plan to another), we're hitting a snag in Production.
When we try to upgrade a plan without using the TestCard functionality in Production (real payment with actual money), it just doesn't seem to work. We've already reached out to our subscription service provider, and they suggested that we connect with google team for further support.
This feature is crucial for us, as it allows users to easily switch between plans and enjoy different benefits. I've attached a screenshot of the error we're seeing when trying to upgrade without the TestCard.
enter image description here
What is done: When we try to upgrade a plan without using the TestCard functionality in Production (real payment with actual money), it just doesn't seem to work, but throws us this error. Meanwhile, the upgrade works successfully with Google Play TestCard functionality (within a gap of 1 hour)
